# Show by strict application of the definition that the closure of $|z - z_0| < \delta$ is $|z - z_0| \leq \delta$.}

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Show by strict application of the definition that the closure of $|z - z_0| < \delta$ is $|z - z_0| \leq \delta$.}

This problem comes from Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, problem 3.1.2.3. To prove this proposition, we need to show that the set is closed, and then that it is the closure, i.e., the smallest closed set containing it. I do not understand how the choice of $w$ is made in this solution, and why, when proving it is the closure, after choosing $w$, the proof proceeds with the steps presented to conclude that it is indeed a closure.

The solutions I find is https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/demason/Ahlfors%20Exercises.pdf

Solution: We show that $|z - z_0| \leq \delta$ is closed by showing $|z - z_0| > \delta$ is open. Let z be such that $|z - z_0| > \delta$ and set $r = |z - z_0| - \delta$. The minimum distance between a point $w$ with $|w - z| \leq r$ and $z_0$ is attained at $w = z + r(z_0 - z)/|z_0 - z|$. Then,
\begin{align*}
|w - z_0| &= |z - z_0 + (1 - \frac{\delta}{|z - z_0|})(z_0 - z)| = \delta. \\
\end{align*}
But, note that $|w - z| = r$ so that in fact if $w \in B(z, r)$ then $|w - z_0| > \delta$.
Since $|z - z_0| \leq \delta$ (denoted S) is closed, it follows that $\operatorname{Cl}(B(z_0, \delta)) \subset S$.

Now let $U$ be open and disjoint from $B(z_0, \delta)$. We show that $U$ is disjoint from $S$. So, let $z \in S$ be such that $|z - z_0| = \delta$. Suppose that $z \in U$. Since $U$ is open, there exists an $\delta > r > 0$ such that $B(z,r) \subset U$. Consider the point $w = z + \frac{r}{2}(z_0 - z)/|z - z_0|$. We see that
\begin{align*}
|w - z| &= |z - z + \frac{r}{2}(z_0 - z)/
|z - z_0|| = \frac{r}{2}, \\
|w - z_0| &=|z - z_0 + \frac{r}{2}(z_0 - z)/\delta| = \frac{1}{\delta}|\delta(z - z_0) + \frac{r}{2}(z_0 - z)| = \left|\frac{r}{2} - \delta\right| < \delta.
\end{align*}
Hence, $w \in B(z_0, \delta) \cap B(z, r)$, a contradiction since $B(z_0, \delta) \cap U = \emptyset$. This shows that every closed set containing $B(z_0, \delta)$ must contain $S$. Hence, $S = \operatorname{Cl}(B(z_0, \delta))$.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are two proofs there. The second one begins at "Now let $U$ be open and disjoint from $B (z_0, \delta)$"...

The first proof shows that $\mathbb{C} - S$ is open, which means that $S$ must be closed, by definition. This is done by showing that for each $z \in \mathbb{C} - S$, that there is a basis element $B (z, r_z)$ that is contained in $\mathbb{C} - S$. The point of introducing $w$ is to show this containment.

Comment: +1 but I would rather say that "the second one begins at" the sentence just afer ("Now let $U$ be open...").

Comment: @AnneBauval Right, thanks! Edited.

Comment: in my class, If $A$ is an open set, then $A$ is a neighborhood of each of its elements. That is, for any $y \in A$, there exists a neighborhood $B(y,\delta)$ such that the neighborhood $B(y,\delta)$ is contained in $A$.
how does it show it's an open set?

Comment: @liyushu Just take $A = \bigcup_{y \in A} B (y, \delta_y)$; i.e., $A$ is an arbitrary union of open sets, so it is open.

Comment: @K.Jiang Yeah, that is to demonstrate the following step, but Why does this step hold true: But, note that $|w - z| = r$ so that in fact if $w \in B(z, r)$ then $|w - z_0| > \delta$.Didn't we just state earlier that  $|w - z_0| = \delta$?